# Custom Post Type Titles WordPress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Good day,

Im not very good at PHP but did some searching.

I have Custom post types that users can add listings to the website. I wanted titles uniform so that it looks professional and not like a donkey's backside. The title is generated by 3 custom meta fields. Year, Make and Model. The client will add more products in future how can I solve this?

For a single post type it works fine but the moment I add a second one it bombs out.

Would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.

```php
function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'caravan_post') {
    $event_year = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'caravan_year' , true);  
    $event_date = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'_caravan_make',true);
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], '_caravan_model' , true);
    $event_title = $event_year . ' ' . $event_date . ' ' . $event_venue;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);

    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  
  else {
      function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'motorhome') {
    $event_year = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'mh-year' , true);  
    $event_date = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'mh-make',true);
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'mh-model' , true);
    $event_title = $event_year . ' ' . $event_date . ' ' . $event_venue;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);

    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_event_title' , '10', 2 );
```

**Update**
I manged to play around and did some more digging and this seems to work. But to add so many else if statements might get to much when new custom post types get added would still appreciate a cleaner way to do this

```php
function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'caravan_post') {
    $event_year = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'caravan_year' , true);  
    $event_date = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'_caravan_make',true);
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], '_caravan_model' , true);
    $event_title = $event_year . ' ' . $event_date . ' ' . $event_venue;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);

    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  
  else 
  if($data['post_type'] == 'motorhome') {
    $event_year = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'mh-year' , true);  
    $event_date = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'mh-make',true);
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'mh-model' , true);
    $event_title = $event_year . ' ' . $event_date . ' ' . $event_venue;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);

    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_event_title' , '10', 2 );
```

Comment: Please note that this is code i cpoied from another forum so the variables $event_year $event_date $event_title i left as is as i am not shure how it will impact if i change these things. Again not very good at PHP :-(

Comment: Anyone that can point me into the right direction?